Time for displacement under gravitational force
Let two particles $A,B$, say, of the same mass $m$ on Eucledean plane and with distance $l$.
Suppose that there is no friction, hence the only force on each particle is the gravitational from the other.
How could we consider a way to find the time needed for $A$  to approach the middle of the segment $AB$ (i.e. to going through $l/2$)?
I conclude the equation: $$-G\frac{m}{r^2}=a \ ,$$ but it seems difficult to solve. Is there a way to think differently?

use $r(t)$ and $a=r''(t)$ and solve the differential equation .

@trula It is not so easy to solve $r^2r''=C$, where $C$ a constant.

@trula The ode can be solved by multiplying with velocity both sides. Though we will get an expression $v=v(r)$. What about time?

Having a first integral $r'(t)=f(r(t))$ you can solve for r(t).

@trula If you find a solution or the form $r=r(t)$, you can write it here.

Comments are not the place to answer questions, especially closed ones. Comments shouldn't be used for hints or partial answers either
